# How to dynamically center a div over another div using offsetWidth and offsetLeft

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, centering

How do I set `left` on a  `div` so that it always appears centered over another `div` despite varying in width?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y04nse5x/

I'm trying to get each label to align perfectly over the dot, without needing a container. I'm sure this is possible with`offsetWidth` and `offsetLeft`, but I just can't get the math right.

The dots are placed in arbitrary locations on the page, and each dot has a `mouseover` event listener that will place a label over the dot. I can get the label to appear over the dot using `offsetLeft` but it's not centered, because the label can differ in width due to different text that depends on which dot it is appearing over.

My actual website where I'm having this problem: http://briennakh.me/world-around-you/ (hover on the menu buttons on the top right)

Answer (score 2):

In your CSS, you're setting the `left` of the description. Let's look at what the `left` is equal to.
[image]

hopefully my diagram made sense, thus:

```
var leftValue = this.offsetLeft-(description.offsetWidth-this.offsetWidth)/2;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y04nse5x/1/

Answer (score 1):

You have to take account on description width and button width.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/khe8j2ms/

But I would probably use additional container and style:

```
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to do it an easier way in the future, probably more maintainable